# "gnustep-config --objc-flags" no output

Tags: objective-c, ubuntu, docker, gnustep

I try to do "gnustep-config --objc-flags" inside Docker/ubuntu and it gives me no output.
Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y fp-ide nodejs php5 ruby build-essential gobjc gnustep gnustep-devel
RUN ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
RUN useradd john
```

Comment: Have you created an image, started this image, and run a `docker exec -it` inside it ? Do you have a valid display (if needed) ? What gives `docker exec -it yourcontainer env` ?

Answer (score 0):

Tried to reproduce your issue. Found what is missing from this [bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1204510)

```
apt install make
```